# Есть ли библиотеки или способы для работы с CLI(Command Line Interface) средой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Код:

```
from os import system
from colorama import Fore, Style


def work_in_mac_os():
    system('clear')
    print(Fore.GREEN + 'Проверим список подключенных устройств: ' + Style.RESET_ALL)
    system('ls /dev/tty.*')
    # system('ls /dev/cu.*')  # Будет работать также.
    system('sudo screen ' + input('Скопируйте и вставте устройство в поле (без лишних символов): '))
    # Метка 1
    # бла бла
    # бла бла (остальной код)


work_in_mac_os()
```

Сам код работает хорошо. Проблема заключается в том, чего я хочу. Пишу любительскую программу, которая будет подключаться к коммутатору через `Console`(COM USB) и совершать настройки с системой.

Но как только программа доходит до строки `system('sudo screen ' + input('Скопируйте и вставьте устройство в поле (без лишних символов): '))` код останавливается, дальше будет работать сам терминал, ибо я буду внутри коммутатора, настраивать сам вручную. То есть использование моего кода становится бессмысленной и автоматизацией здесь и не пахнет. Код продолжит работать тогда, когда я остановлю работу с коммутатором. Значит код работать не будет.

Есть ли способ работать в CLI(Command Line Interface) среде коммутатора? Может есть библиотеки?

Вопрос для меня очень интересный, ибо в интернете ничего похожего найти не могу.

Comment: Можно через [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) подключаться или просто как к [файловому объекту](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50401909/4752653) (если дополнительных настроек не требуется)

Comment: С помощью ваших вышеперечисленных методов, я смогу настраивать коммутатор с помощью кода? Если конкретнее: установка логина и пароля, настройка интерфейсов, vlan'ов и т.д.

Comment: Вы можете через метод write посылать те же самые команды текстом, что вы отправляли через screen.

Comment: Я попробую, спасибо. Отвечу в среду, как получу на пользование коммутатор.

Comment: @insolor Напишите ответ так как вы первый предложили ответ. А то вопрос висит как неотвеченый. Спасибо.

Comment: @Bulat_Akhmadeev Вы сами можете ответить на свой вопрос. Такое часто бывает если человек разобрался с вопросом сам или вопрос решен в коментарии. Спасибо.